# How to get the circular path in svg?

Tags: svg

I need draw a stroke arc around the circle

```
Circle 
 cx=110,cy=60,r=50

Path 
  d=M60,60 A50,50 0 0,1 160,60

<svg style="position:absolute" id="svg_test" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
    <circle style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" cx="110" cy="60" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#e4e4e4" stroke-width="2"></circle> 
    <path id="svgpath" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" fill="none" stroke="#16a6b6" d="M60,60 A50,50 0 0,1 160,60" stroke-width="2"></path> 
</svg>
```

How to determine the path if cx,cy and r is changed?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378356/drawing-multiple-circular-arcs-dynamically-using-svg) formula is given d="M cx cy+r+d A r+d r+d 0 0 0 cx+r+d cy".

Computed path M110, 110+d A50+d, 50 0 0 0 150,60 using above cx and cy does not match the value M60,60 A50,50 0 0,1 160,60

What should be the value of d?

[image: circle]

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bl_praveen2004/3C8JA/1/)

Comment: What is `d` meant to represent? The degree around the circle?

Comment: What is d value meant in the formula?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your question is, or what you ar trying to achieve.

The formula will draw an arc that covers quarter of a circle (110,110 round to 160,60 - the lower right quadrant).  If you want more than that, you will have to alter the formula.

Where did you get "M60,60 A50,50 0 0,1 160,60" from?  Why are you expecting it to match the path generated by the formula?

Comment: It was in the example [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230148/create-svg-progress-circle). it covers quarter of the cirle starting from 180deg. How to start from 90deg?

Comment: Where do you want the arc to start and where do you want it to end?

Comment: I want to start the arc at 90deg and animate the arc to 0deg

Comment: What direction are you calling 0 degrees? Rightwards?  And 90 deg clockwise or anti-clockwise?  You might want to draw a picture of what you want and add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find both the end points of the arc. each time your `cx`, `cy` and `r` is changed in order to update the path.

```
firstX = cx + (Math.cos(firstAngle * (Math.PI / 180)) * r);
firstY = cy - (Math.sin(firstAngle * (Math.PI / 180)) * r);

secondX = cx + (Math.cos(secondAngle * (Math.PI / 180)) * r);
secondY = cy - (Math.sin(secondAngle * (Math.PI / 180)) * r);

'M ' + firstX + ',' + firstY + ' A' + r + ',' + r + ' 0 1 0 ' + secondX + ',' + secondY
```

Comment: I have created a fiddle.

Comment: I've given the computed path. Just forget about the d

Comment: check the **large-arc-flag** and **sweep-flag**. what you might be lookinng for is `'M ' + firstX + ',' + firstY + ' A' + r + ',' + r + ' 0 0 1 ' + secondX + ',' + secondY`